# SQL Noob compare table in opencart

Tags: sql, database, phpmyadmin, e-commerce, opencart

I have one table called VEGAN with model numbers that i want 3800 rows with model or SKU codes. thats it.

In the main oc_products table there are 15000 products / rows with over 20 columns, In one of those columsn there is a control for enabled which can be set to 0 or 1.

I want to Disable all products in the main oc_products table if they are not in the VEGAN table, or Disable(set status to 0) them all first and Enable them (set status to 1) if they are in the Vegan Table.

So far I have come up with this... I am a first timer here.

FIRST DISABLE EVERYTHING...

UPDATE `oc_product`
SET `status`= '0'
WHERE 1

then...

UPDATE oc_product SET `status`= '1' WHERE 'ocproduct.model' = ‘VEGAN.SKU'

It doesn't work and Im stuck, 
please help.

Comment: You probably want something like `WHERE ocproduct.model IN(SELECT SKU FROM VEGAN)`

Comment: It looks like you're using `'` for the column in the `WHERE` clause - try using backticks (`\``) instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this query...

```
update oc_product set status = 1 where model in (select sku from vegan)
```

This assumes that `oc_product.model` matches `vegan.sku`.

Any `vegan.sku` with a matching `oc_product.model` will get `oc_product.status` set to `1`.

Comment: This is the first solution I tried and it worked immediately. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

For your second update statement you should do something like:

```
UPDATE oc_product SET status = '1' 
WHERE ocproduct.model IN (SELECT SKU FROM Vegan)
```

or you can use the alternate format:

```
UPDATE oc_product SET status = '1'
FROM oc_product
INNER JOIN Vegan
  ON oc_product.model = Vegan.SKU
```